# Run a Macro within a protected workbook

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run a Macro in excel. I am having an issue, the problem is that I want to protect all the sheets that the macro is going to generate. I have this piece of code to generate the sheet name:

```
**ActiveSheet.Name = "Week " & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Range("b5"))**
```

I have being researching and one way to run the macro within a file with a password is this one:

```
**ActiveSheet.Select
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="OSDA06"
 ActiveSheet.Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect Password:="OSDA06"**
```

but with this code I get the protection only in the active sheet, not the full workbook.

How can I select all the sheets instead ActiveSheet.Select (I tried sheets.select, activeworkbook.select, activeworksheet.select and none of them are working)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a For loop to run through all the worksheets.

```
Dim ws as variant

For Each ws in ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    ws.Unprotect Password:="OSDA06"
next ws
```

Comment: I'd dim ws as Worksheet more efficient.

Answer (score 1):

thank you so much for your answer, I am trying now with the piece of code that you gave me, and it is working but with a small issue.
My macro creates a new worksheet with the word week plus the number of the week, so, my first sheet is "week 24" when I run the macro with your code creates "week 25" , If I am in sheet "Week 25" and try to run the macro again, I get this error "the name is already taken" and generates the sheet "week 25 (2)". If I delete that sheet and run the macro again, works perfectly, generates "week 26" . If I am in sheet "Week 26" and try to generate another sheet, the same thing happens , generate week 26 (2), I have to delete it and try again and then generates" week 27"

this is all my code

```
Sub WeeklyWorksheet()


   Dim wsheet As Worksheet
    For Each wsheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    wsheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    Next wsheet

    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Range("B2:P2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Week "
    ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value + 7
    Range("C7:C42,D7:D42").Select
    Range("D7").Activate
    Selection.ClearContents
    Range("F7:G42,I7:J42,L7:M42,O7:P42").Select
    Range("O7").Activate
    Selection.ClearContents
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Week " & WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Range("b5"))

    For Each wsheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    wsheet.Protect Password:="password"
    Next wsheet

End Sub
```

Comment: How many worksheets are you trying to create? Is this dynamic based on the value in cell b5?

Comment: I am trying to create the weeks of the year , so basically from week 24 to week 52

Answer (score 1):

thank you so much for your help, I tried with the last code you gave me and I hade to do some modifications (as you said), but the final result was that the button that I am using it generated the 52 sheets at one time.

so, what I did was:

instead of

```
For Each wsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    wsheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    Next wsheet
```

I used

```
ActiveSheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
```

The rest of the code I left it the same

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I haven't tested this code so it may need some modification. In general consider avoiding using select. It'll save you some computational time and allow you to act directly on the data.

```
For Each wsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    wsheet.Unprotect Password:="password"
    Next wsheet

For i = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(Now()) to 52
    ActiveSheet.Copy After:=Sheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Range("B2:P2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Week "
    ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value = ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value + 7
    Range("C7::D42").ClearContents
    Range("F7:G42,I7:J42,L7:M42,O7:P42").ClearContents
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Week " & i
next i

    For Each wsheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    wsheet.Protect Password:="password"
    Next wsheet
```